# Regex, how to return a set of words present in a title?

Tags: regex

In the example below, would the correct result be to return only the headings between id 9 and 15? the closest I got was:

((^| )(FED[A-Z]*|(ESC[A-Z]*)|(AGRO[A-Z]*)|(CENT[A-Z]*)|(CTR[A-Z]*)|(INST[A-Z]*)|(EDUC[A-Z]*)|(SCI[A-Z]*)|(TEC[A-Z]*))( |$))

**Note: the FED [A-Z] * argument must always be present with the combination of at least one of the terms listed.
Titles containing the term UNIV [A-Z] * must return false.**

| ID | TEXT | CURRENT RETURN | EXPECTED RETURN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INST NACL MATEMAT PURA | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2 | PARA FED UNIV, TOXICOL LAB | TRUE | FALSE |
| 3 | CTR, BR12020330 TAUBATE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4 | VICENTE LINHARES ST | TRUE | FALSE |
| 5 | ALBERT EINSTEIN AVE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 6 | REG TECN CRIMINALIST | TRUE | FALSE |
| 7 | NASCIMENTO CASTRO AVE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 8 | SAO PAULO FED UNIV, COLL AGR SCI, DEPT CROP SCI, BOTUCATU, SP, BRAZIL | TRUE | FALSE |
| 9 | INST FED CIENCIA TECNOL SUL MINAS, CAMPUS POCOS DE CALDAS | TRUE | TRUE |
| 10 | INST FED EDUC PERNAMBUCO IFPE, RECIFE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 11 | INST FED MINAS GERAIS, CAMPUS CONGONHAS | TRUE | TRUE |
| 12 | INST FED ECN TECNOL NORTE MINAS | TRUE | TRUE |
| 13 | CTR FED EDUC TECNOL OURO PRETO | TRUE | TRUE |
| 14 | FED INST AMPUS GARANHUNS | TRUE | TRUE |
| 15 | INST FED PERNAMBUCO BRASIL | FALSE | TRUE |

*More exemples: https://regex101.com/r/reVgya/1*

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: the alternations can be reduced to `(FED|ESC|AGRO|CIE|CENT|CTR|CRT|INST|EDUC|SCI|TEC)[A-Z]*` I think.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, this is a language (generic regular expression).

Comment: @VishalSingh, grateful for the simplification. But still, in the example, you select the titles with the id from 1 to 8. They must not be selected.

Comment: @cnauber You have selected PCRE2 in the regex101 tool, but there are more regex flavours https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines

Comment: @Thefourthbird, yes. But, this pattern is what works in mysql, as far as I know.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? 5.7 and 8.0 use different regex engines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I'm using version 8.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you need `'^(?!.*\\bUNIV\\b)(?=.*\\bFED\\b).*\\b(FED|ESC|AGRO|CIE|CENT|CTR|CRT|INST|EDUC|SCI|TEC)\\b'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thankful. I believe it is the solution. I will test it here on my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
WHERE col RLIKE '^(?!.*\\bUNIV\\b)(?=.*\\bFED\\b).*\\b(FED|ESC|AGRO|CIE|CENT|CTR|CRT|INST|EDUC|SCI|TEC)\\b'
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IQ1068/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\bUNIV\b)` - a negative lookahead check: there must be NO `UNIV` whole word in the string
- `(?=.*\bFED\b)` - a positive lookahead check: there must be a `FED` whole word in the string
- `.*\b(FED|ESC|AGRO|CIE|CENT|CTR|CRT|INST|EDUC|SCI|TEC)\b` - after any zero or more chars other than line break chars, there must be a whole word from the list of alternations.